# Python - Merge a list of dictionaries based on 2 values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries that look like this:

```
[
  {
    'accountId': 952940,
    'objectType': 'Creative',
    'objectId': 1361295595
  },
  {
    'accountId': 7037,
    'objectType': 'Placement',
    'objectId': 2713583698
  },
  {
    'accountId': 7037,
    'objectType': 'Placement',
    'objectId': 271354409
  },
  {
    'accountId': 7037,
    'objectType': 'Ad',
    'objectId': 1234565698
  }
]
```

I want to group them by accountId and objectType, so the final output looks like this:

```
[
  {
    'accountId': 959740,
    'objectType': 'Creative',
    'objectId': 136139595
  },
  {
    'accountId': 7037,
    'objectType': 'Placement',
    'objectId': [275765698,279984409]
  },
  {
    'accountId': 7037,
    'objectType': 'Ad',
    'objectId': 1234565698
  }
]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you mind using `pandas`?

Comment: Pandas would be acceptable for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `defaultdict` keyed by the group terms:

```
from collections import defaultdict

grouped = defaultdict(list)
for entry in my_list:
    grouped[(entry['accountId'], entry['objectType'])].append(entry['objectId'])

new_list = [{'accountId': k[0], 'objectType': k[1], 'objectId': v}
            for k, v in grouped.items()]
```

Note that the `objectId` will always contain a list in the result even if it's only a single item.

Answer (score 0):

if using pandas is acceptable; try this way:

```
df = df.groupby(['accountId', 'objectType']).agg(list).reset_index()
print(df.to_dict(orient='records'))

[{'accountId': 7037, 'objectType': 'Ad', 'objectId': [1234565698]}, {'accountId': 7037, 'objectType': 'Placement', 'objectId': [2713583698, 271354409]}, {'accountId': 952940, 'objectType': 'Creative', 'objectId': [1361295595]}]
```

Comment: you might find useful  `as_index=False` in `groupby`

Comment: @Marat, nice catch :) . using as_index= False probably won't need to do reset_index.